# ListFragment onPrepareOptionsMenu called before onCreate. Why and How to Fix / Bypass?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

Okay, so I've got FavoritesList extending GalleryList which extends ListFragment:

```java
public static class FavoritesList extends GalleryList {

    public static FavoritesList newInstance(int page) {
        FavoritesList list = new FavoritesList();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("page", page);
        list.setArguments(args);

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getGalleries(fav, preferences.getString("sort"+fav, "date desc"));
        listAdapter = new GalleryListAdapter(activity, cursor);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 8, "Remove All");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        //listAdapter is null the first time this is called...

        if (listAdapter != null && listlistAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.filter).setEnabled(false);
            menu.findItem(0).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.filter).setEnabled(true);
            menu.findItem(0).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem: onPrepareOptionsMenu is called *before* onCreate (where I initialize listAdapter) when loading this Fragment, and it *isn't* called again before the options menu is shown for the first time!

The [Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)) is simply wrong when it claims onPrepareOptionsMenu "is called *right before* the menu is shown, *every time* it is shown."

p.s. I'm using the Android Support Library (v4). Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as silly as this is, here is a functioning workaround:

```java
public static class FavoritesList extends GalleryList {

    Menu optionsMenu;

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);

        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getGalleries(fav, preferences.getString("sort"+fav, "date desc"));
        listAdapter = new GalleryListAdapter(activity, cursor);
        setListAdapter(listAdapter);

        if (optionsMenu != null) {
            onPrepareOptionsMenu(optionsMenu);
        }
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        optionsMenu = menu;

        if (listAdapter != null && listAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.filter).setEnabled(false);
            menu.findItem(0).setEnabled(false);
        }
        else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.filter).setEnabled(true);
            menu.findItem(0).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I've grabbed the options menu during the first run of onPrepareOptionsMenu, then called it again once listAdapter has been initialized.

**edit:** evidently without checking if optionsMenu is null, this will break on certain phones. I should have realized.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` on your `onCreate()`. Make sure to check if your list adapter is `null` on `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: invalidateOptionMenu is only available from API level 11 whereas my minSdkVersion is 8. Additionally, it only seems to be available to Activities, not Fragments.