# onCreateOptionsMenu called before onCreate android

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-listfragment, android-optionsmenu

I am beginner to android and i am developing small android application. In my application I am using Sherlock library. My application contains one main activity and two fragments. On of my list fragment structure looks like

```
public class MyCards extends SherlockListFragment
        {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside fragment on create");

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside on activity created");
    }

    private void displayCards(int type) {

        Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside display cards");

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycards, container, false);

        View view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.empty_card, container, false);
        return view;

    }

    /*@Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

    optionsMenu = menu;
    }*/

    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_type2, menu);

        Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside on create option menu");
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) menu.findItem(R.id.cardType)
                .getActionView();

        SpinnerAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext(), R.array.card_action_list,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter); // set the adapter

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int pos, long id) {
                displayCards(pos);
                Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside on option selected");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                displayCards(0);
                Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside on no option selection");
            }

        });


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!", "inside option select listener");

    }

}
```

Now my problem is that when I switch fro one fragment to another fragment for first time 
it gives following log output

```
01-04 00:54:06.997: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(2575): inside on create option menu
01-04 00:54:06.997: W/KeyCharacterMap(2575): No keyboard for id -1
01-04 00:54:06.997: W/KeyCharacterMap(2575): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-04 00:54:07.020: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(2575): inside fragment on create
01-04 00:54:07.036: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(2575): inside on activity created
```

That mean on create option called before onfragment create and on activity create . and it also giving two warning. This work with out any error. But I am not able to display my list view

Now when I again switch to same fragment(for second time) it gives following log output

```
02-07 10:05:10.983: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(15844): inside on create option menu
02-07 10:05:11.023: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(15844): inside fragment on create
02-07 10:05:11.043: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(15844): inside on activity created
02-07 10:05:11.113: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(15844): inside display cards
02-07 10:05:11.133: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(15844): inside on option selected
```

this time it's not giving any warning and working properly. Also displaying my list view.
But for the first time it's not working properly..
Another point is that when I ran it on higher version of android its working fine. But If i ran it on lower version of android like 2.3.3  i shows such behavior.. 
I read about this [ListFragment onPrepareOptionsMenu called before onCreate. Why and How to Fix / Bypass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374816/listfragment-onprepareoptionsmenu-called-before-oncreate-why-and-how-to-fix-b)   But i am not able to solve this problem.

if I define `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` inside `onActivityCreated` it gives following output

```
01-04 03:32:38.622: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(8157): inside fragment on create
01-04 03:32:38.653: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(8157): inside on activity created
01-04 03:32:38.692: I/!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!(8157): inside on create option menu
01-04 03:32:38.700: W/KeyCharacterMap(8157): No keyboard for id -1
01-04 03:32:38.700: W/KeyCharacterMap(8157): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
```

I also tried to set setHasOptionsMenu for my fragment where actual fragment transaction takes place like below..

```
@Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            MyCards mc = new MyCards();
            mc.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
            ft = mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName(),
                        mArgs);

                ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
                ft.commit();
            }
```

and still it giving same problem.

any problem with my code or some thing else?
So how to solve this problem.
Need help...
thank you...

Comment: Are you sure it's not because you're calling `setHasOptionsMenu` before doing the logging in onCreate?

Comment: Hi zharf thank you for reply. see my edited question.. and changed log output.. But this is not solving my problem..

Answer (score 28):

write `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` in `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)` method.

Comment: the reasoning: for some versions, the support library will immediately create the menubar on calling setHasOptionsMenu(true)...this can possibly cause errors if you, for example, needed the layout to already be inflated, or need some instance variables populated from the inflated layout.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it works like that, but do this:
Set option `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in your Activity when you are adding your fragment to it.

For example:

```
//Activity class
YourListFragment f = new YourListFragment();

f.setHasOptionsMenu(true); //here

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.your_list_fragment_container, f).commit();
```

And delete setting it in your fragment's code. It worked for me.

Comment: Hi michal thank you for quick reply.. I tried u r solution. In my application i am using tabs. In my ontabselected method i tried your solution but its not working for me. I tried in following manner .`MyCards my_card = new MyCards()` and `my_card.setHasOptionsMenu(true)`.... But its not working. This method not even work on latest version of android for me. Any other solution. Thank you for help...

Comment: What do you mean this method not even work? It's working for me on android 2.3 as fine as on 4.2.

Comment: hi michal thank you for reply. I tried it on 2.3.3 and ics version but it's not working... Is there anything wrong with my code ... Need help.

Comment: Post code of your Tab Activity or at least a piece of it where you are actually adding fragment's to it.

Comment: Michal can you plz go through my edited question. In onTabSelected I tried to set setHasOptionsMenu option .

Comment: Did you remove setHasOptionsMenu(true) from your Fragment's onCreate()?

Comment: Yeha I removed it from my fragment oncreate();

Comment: This does really help to get rid of the Android's idiosyncrasy. BTW, I moved the call to `setHasOptionsMenu` into fragment's constructor, because in activity I have common part of code which creates  fragments of different classes, and not all of them have options menu.