# Rare occurrence of null injected field

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Rarely, when I try accessing an injected field, the application would crash because that accessed field is null. I have no way to reproduce it, and it's not supposed to happen to begin with.
Any idea why this might happen and how to avoid it?

The field is being injected inside a fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Inject StubManager mStubManager;
    ....
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Application.getAppComponent().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        ....
        menu.findItem(R.id.item_id)
            .setEnabled(!mStubManager.isRunning());
    }
}
```

The app component looks like the below, and is initialized in the **Application** class:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        MyModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
    StubManager stubManager();

    void inject(MyFragment target);
}
```

Comment: If your field is not `@Nullable` it will not be `null` after Dagger injected it. You should verify when and how you call your injection, since the only way this would be null would be if you access your field before the injection was done

Comment: `@Inject StubManager mStubManager;` how when where?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I modified the question so it should be clearer now.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Is it possible that I would be accessing the field before injection if the Fragment was already injected when the component was initialized at Application class creation? And, if that's the case, wouldn't it be easier to reproduce? I was never able to reproduce and it rarely happens (10 crash instances between hundreds of thousands of users)

Comment: well it's most likely something that happens after process death then. I always inject fragments in their no-arg constructors, and if it's subscoped by activity then I always set that up before `super.onCreate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your `inject` call to `onAttach` before calling `super`.

---

As [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1837367/david-medenjak) mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44407425/rare-occurrence-of-null-injected-field#comment75815872_44407425), if you have a non-@Nullable field that Dagger successfully injects most of the time, then it is likely not a Dagger bug, but rather one of Android lifecycle or Java multithreading. I'm guessing the former is happening here.

Though I don't have a doubtless reason offhand in code or docs, [anecdotally there seem to be cases where the options menu is prepared before `onCreate`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12374816/1426891), and a cursory glance at the Android open source code for [FragmentManager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java#2162) and [Activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#3161) (as well as the [menu docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#ChangingTheMenu)) suggest that the Fragment isn't guaranteed to be created and that the options menu is considered open as long as the action bar is visible. If so, this would be a case where you would read a `null` value from your injected field. You might be able to test this by opening your options menu (if you aren't using ActionBar), using the home button or clicking a notification to navigate away from your Activity, and then returning to your Activity such that it has to reattach the Fragment and recreate its options menu. This might be more reproducible if you enable the development option "Don't keep activities" to simulate memory pressure that would cause your Activity to be destroyed, which would otherwise be relatively random and infrequent on users' devices.

I suspect your injection may simply be happening too *late*: Note that [`onAttach` is called before `onCreate` is called](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Lifecycle), such that the docs for `dagger.android` suggest [injecting in `onAttach` before the call to `super.onAttach`](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html#when-to-inject). This is the earliest, most consistent, and recommended place to perform injection in Fragments, particularly if your Fragment inherits from a base Fragment class: if the superclass has any `@Inject` fields that it uses in `onCreate` or `onAttach`, those will also be `null` with your `inject` call where it is.

Comment: You're perfectly right, the only thing is that **onPrepareOptionsMenu** is even called before the **onAttach** due to a certain hack we applied. So I'll be injecting there. Thanks :)